# Antlr4 inconsistent tokenizing

Tags: antlr4

I am parsing a SQL like language using antlr 4.

Normal SQL's works fine.

I also have to support a special case which defines this query as external handled and therefor I just have to copy stuff.

for example:
SELECT a,b,c FROM EX.database.table WHERE A > 5

The only important part here is EX.database.table - Everything else is just copied.

The problem is with stuff like SELECT a AS Afield. Antlr recognizes AS as a token and breaks the line to several parts. I want it as a full line. I'd like antlr to consider the AS here as part of the string instead of a token.

Can this be done or should I create another grammar?

This is the grammar:

```
    select_from_external_statement :
        SELECT  external_data_source_Expression                 
        FROM    exteranl_data_source_definition 
        (external_data_source_Expression)?      
;

external_data_source_Expression:    expr;
exteranl_data_source_definition:    EX '.' expr '.' expr;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming external_data_source_Expression contains the keyword AS, I would make a more specific rule of what external_data_source_Expression really means.  The parser rule below should get you any number of columns and should handle the alias just fine.  The capitalized rules below are the lexer rules.  I didn't define what they all mean, but I suppose you can match them all to a string.

```
select_from_external_statement:
  SELECT_KEYWORD external_data_source_Expression FROM_KEYWORD external_data_source_definition ;

external_data_source_definition:
  EXTERNAL_SERVER '.' SCHEMA '.' TABLE ;

external_data_source_Expression: 
  column_with_alias (',' column_with_alias)* ;

column_with_alias:
  COLUMN AS_KEYWORD ALIAS ;

SELECT_KEYWORD: 
  'SELECT' ;

FROM_KEYWORD:
  'FROM' ;

AS_KEYWORD: 
  'AS' ;
```

I'd actually handle it differently and use left recursion for a nested query (assuming external query is a nested query), so the parser rule calls itself.  In which case, the SQL query would look identical to the external SQL query, if they share the same syntax.  I don't know enough about your language to understand what you're after though.